# Ruby on Rails Time In / Time Out Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to record a 'time_in', and 'time_out' record on a model called 'timeclock'. Here is what I am trying to do but can't get to work!

1. Check the last timeclock entry and see if it has both 'time_in' and 'time_out' records filled in. If so, then create a new record (like this?):

   ```
   form_for([@employee, @employee.timeclocks.build]) do |f|

     f.hidden_field :time_in, :value => @current_time 

     f.submit "Clock In"

   end
   ```
2. If there's already a timeclock record that is incomplete (has a 'time_in' record but not a 'time_out' record, render a form or update the last record.

I have been able to get the time records into the db, but never on the same data-record, like this: http://cl.ly/E0Rg (image)

Does that make sense? If you need some clarifying questions, don't hesitate to ask! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with the code you present you always create new record as @employee.timeclocks.build is used to create record.

If you want tu update a record you should fetch it first an then pass this record in the form_for method

to fetch a record use @employee.timeclocks.find fappropriate where clause to get the record you want to update

```
form_for([@employee, @timeclock]) do |f|

  f.hidden_field :time_in, :value => @current_time 

  f.submit "Clock In"

end
```

where you set @timeclock in you controller either in with a new record or with the record you want to update

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This works perfectly. If I had 15 rep I would vote up your answer :( Sorry!